# How can I apply blur effect only on the background of my mainwindow?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

[what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZAVL.png)
I am learning how to use pyqt5 with this project of mine.

I tried downloading something called BlurWindow but it kept giving me a parameter error so switched back to trying to use QGraphicBlurEffect but it blurs everything inside my MainWindow

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from BlurWindow.blurWindow import blur

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    loadUi(r'D:\Workspace\Qt Designer\blur bg\blurtest.ui',self)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    hWnd = self.winId()
    print(hWnd)
    blur(hWnd)

    self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")


app=QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow=MainWindow()
widget=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedHeight(600)
widget.setFixedWidth(800)
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: this is what i got]

Comment: Your image doesn't show any blur at all.

Comment: @musicamante hey, sorry it was not so visible earlier. i have updated the screenshot. it was a ss of the sidebar in windows settings.
as far as i can say, it's opacity+blur effect, i don't know how to apply a blur effect in pyqt5 without blurring everything inside the window

Comment: QGraphicsEffect are applied to the widgets contents, not their "background". If you did attempt to use BlurWindow, then just show us what you tried and the error you got.

Comment: @musicmante there you go, this is what i get out of blurwindow

Comment: Still waiting for the error you mentioned.

Comment: @musicamante that error is not appearing anymore. right now the code for blur is not doing anything. my window created in qtdesigner was originally solid black with test text in white in between. now it has become like the default grayish white bg and no blur effect

Comment: Try to remove `setWindowOpacity()` as it may interfere with the effect, and also try to use that `blur()` with a basic window (without any content) in order to rule out possible indirectly related problems. Eventually contact the author of that library or study its sources. Also, don't add QMainWindow to a stacked widget.

Comment: @musicamante removing the setwindowopacity just gives me my original design which i made in qtdesigner. i even removed all the content but still it just gives the same blank window, no transparency nothing. also may i know why should we not add qmainwindow to stacked widget? (sorry i was following how to make this from a youtube video)

Comment: QMainWindow is intended to be a *top level* window, not to be used a child widget. Just use a plain QWidget instead. If you're following a tutorial from "Code First with Hala", then I strongly suggest you to completely disregard it, as it provides a lot of terrible suggestions and bad practices.

Comment: @musicamante omg that was indeed where I was learning from. Thanks, just using mainwindow.show() made it work.
Do you have any suggestions on who else I could watch for learning more?
And how do I mark you as an answer?

Comment: You can't mark comments as answers, and I've not really understood what you changed to make it work. That said, I generally discourage watching video tutorials as main source of learning (mostly because most of those tutorials are made by people that only have generic and superficial experience of the subject they're treating when dealing with complex toolkits as Qt). Start by following *valid* tutorials, like those [listed here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials).

Comment: @musicamante all i had to do was remove everything related to widget at the ending and put mainwindow.show() and it started working
also thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BlurWindow](https://pypi.org/project/BlurWindow/) uses system features to set the background of a *top level window*.

Your problem is that you're applying it to the wrong widget, which is a *child* widget, not a top level one. The top level has no "glass effect" set, so the result is that it won't have any effect applied on it.

The solution is simple: apply the effect to the top level window.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from BlurWindow.blurWindow import blur

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi(r'D:\Workspace\Qt Designer\blur bg\blurtest.ui', self)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            MainWindow {
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        """)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedHeight(600)
widget.setFixedWidth(800)

blur(widget.winId()) # <---
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that:

- QMainWindow is not supposed to be used as a child widget. You should switch to a basic QWidget (or other container widgets like QFrame), meaning that you should create a new "widget" in Designer and copy/paste the content of your previous window to it, otherwise `loadUi()` will throw an exception;
- you should **never** apply generic style sheet properties to parent widgets, as you would get unexpected results (especially with complex widgets, like scroll areas); you should always use proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) (as I did above);